# Sonarqube 5.0: Database schema must be updated

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Before I upgraded Sonar 5.0 I used the internal org.codehaus.**sonar**:sonar-maven-plugin:4.3.2. After the upgrade I used the same plugin in version 5.0 but got the error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:5.0:sonar (default-cli) on project at.biac.offer.pom: Please update sonar-maven-plugin to at least version 2.3
```

Then I switched to org.codehaus.**mojo**:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5 but now I get the following error

```
org.sonar.jpa.session.DatabaseException: Database schema must be updated   [version/required=721/170]. Please browse to your sonar homepage.
```

Is there any way to fix this problem without loosing my analysis data so far?

Answer (score 0):

Database upgrade is a normal step when doing an upgrade of the SonarQube server. You should not lose any data.

Comment: The DB was upgraded successfully during the upgrade process. But now I get the error when I'm running the sonar analysis.

Comment: The ``version/required=721/170`` message indicates that the upgrade did not end smoothly: DB is at version 170, whereas the analysis job expects a version of 721. Maybe you're not connecting to the right database?

Comment: I think the problem is, that I use a different maven plugin for my analysis job now. Otherwise the diff in the version numbers wouldn't make sense. The error message tells me that the required version is 170 but the actual version is 721.

Comment: What about the first error message? Why can't I use the org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:5.0 with Sonar 5.0?

Comment: > I used the internal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.3.2
As you know *internal* means that it should not be used...

Comment: Please provide full logs of the analysis but I guess issue is with configuration of `sonar.host.url`